# wget hangs with -r and -O -

Tags: recursion, stdout, wget, freeze

This is a **VERY** strange `wget` behavior. I'm on debian 7.2.

```
wget -r -O - www.blankwebsite.com
```

hangs forever. And I mean it *hangs*, it isn't searching through the internet,
I can verify it with a `strace`. 
If I do this:

```
while read R
do
   wget -r -O - www.blankwebsite.com
done < smallfile
```

with `smallfile` containing a single line, the command exits in a few seconds.

I tried also with

```
wget -r -O - localhost/test.html
```

with an empty `test.html` file, same results. To me, it sounds like a bug.
Everything runs fine changing `-O -` with `-O myfile` or removing `-r`.
I used `-O -` because I was passing output to `grep`.
Could anyone explain that? Have you seen anything similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course:

```
 wget -r -O file www.blankwebsite.com
```

works, but the BUG is that:

```
 wget -r -O - www.blankwebsite.com
```

hangs!

The same problem is if you create a FIFO

```
mkfifo /tmp/myfifo
wget -r -O /tmp/myfifo www.blankwebsite.com
```

wget, when called with -r option, will try to find HTML "a href=..." tags reading the output file. Since the output file is a FIFO or stdout (ex. HYPHEN char '-') it is not able to find any tag and waits for INPUT. Then you will have a wget process waintg forever on a read system call.

To resolve this you can:
1) Patch wget to handle this case
2) Patch wget to not allow "-r -O -" combination... (Just check that the argument of '-O' is a regular file)
3) Use a workaround like:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/wget.XXXXXX)
wget -r -O $TMPFILE www.blankwebsite.com
grep STRING $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

Comment: I know the form `-O file` works, I know the bug is when using ` -O -` , it's exactly what I wrote. Did you read everything? My question was different. Why does including the code in a `while` work? My questions were: "Can you explain that? " and "have you seen something similar? "

Comment: In the while loop you have a "read" and a redirect "< smalfile" that will close for you the stdout (like ctrl-c will do). So the "wget -r -O -" seems to work because you see the script ending and no wating forever. But, as you may experiment, the effect is that you still download only the first page; so the "-r" option is not working with: "-O -". Just use: "wget -O - www.blanksite.com" instead.

Comment: Aren't you confusing stdout with stdin? `< smallfile` close stdin, not stdout. Same thing for what you said before, `-r` will try to find HTML tags reading ... output? Why it should read output?? Also with the FIFO, wget reads lines from the sites specified, NOT from output! Quite confusing answer...

Comment: Sorry wget output stdin/stdout, I just made a mistake. I try to explain it better. When wget is called with "-r -O-" it reads from the web-site and send output to stdout. But, this is just for the first html-page. The "-r" will search for href tags on the output... With "-O -" you have redirected wget output to stdout, so the "-r" tries to read stdout for finding href tags and do recursion. This is a bug. The same appened with a fifo, as I said in the first answer. Your while loop can be converted in `wget -r -O - www.blankwebiste.com </dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

@tonjo : Can you please try using the following code.

```
wget -r -O file www.blankwebsite.com
```

instead of using

```
 wget -r -O - www.blankwebsite.com
```

Comment: If you read carefully the entire question, I did that and I pointed out the problem is only with the stdout version

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the documentation:

```
 Similarly, using '-r' or '-p' with '-O' may not work as you expect:
 Wget won't just download the first file to FILE and then download
 the rest to their normal names: _all_ downloaded content will be
 placed in FILE.  This was disabled in version 1.11, but has been
 reinstated (with a warning) in 1.11.2, as there are some cases
 where this behavior can actually have some use.
```

That is a known problem, that is also downloaded somehow, using -r and -O with non seekable files doesn't work with the way wget serialize the data directly to the file.