# Grep files in between wget recursive downloads

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, wget

I am trying to recursively download several files using `wget -m`, and I intend to `grep` all of the downloaded files to find specific text. Currently, I can wait for `wget` to fully complete, and then run grep. However, the `wget` process is time consuming as there are many files and instead I would like to show progress by `grep`-ing each file as it downloads and printing to `stdout`, all before the next file downloads.

Example:

```
download file1
  grep file1 >> output.txt
download file2
  grep file2 >> output.txt
...
```

Thanks for any advice on how this could be achieved.

Comment: wget  http://google.com -O - | grep "string"

Comment: I just tested this and the recursion/grep seems to work when I set `-O` to be a file, but when I use `-O -` it stops after the first file.

Comment: yes this work with  single file, but not with recursion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681316/wget-hangs-with-r-and-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As c4f4t0r pointed out

```
 wget -m -O - <wesbites>|grep --color 'pattern'
```

using grep's color function to highlight the patterns may seem helpful especially when dealing with bulky data output to terminal.

EDIT:

Below is a command line you can use. it creates  a file called `file` and save the output messages from wget.Afterwards it tails the message file.

Using awk to find any lines with "saved" and extract filename, then use grep to pattern from filename.

```
 wget -m websites  &> file &  tail -f -n1 file|awk -F "\'|\`"  '/saved/{system( ("grep  --colour pattern ") $2)}'
```

Comment: -mO - doesn't work because wget can't find the next link to recursively download.

Comment: @RogueBaneling hmmm..interesting...answer edited showing a command line you can use

Comment: I played around with that a bit and was able to get it working with this: `wget -m -O file.txt http://google.com 2> /dev/null & sleep 1 && tail -f -n1 file.txt | grep pattern`. Originally the `tail` command was not working and I believe it is because file.txt was not created by the time `tail` was executing, so that is why I added in the `sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Xorg's solution I was able to achieve my desired effect with some minor adjustments:

```
wget -m -O file.txt http://google.com 2> /dev/null & sleep 1 && tail -f -n1 file.txt | grep pattern
```

This will print out all lines that contain `pattern` to `stdout`, and `wget` itself will produce no output visible from the terminal. The `sleep` is included because otherwise `file.txt` would not be created by the time the `tail` command executed.

As a note, this command will miss any results that `wget` downloads within the first second.

Comment: great!..+1 for finding your solution